# Displaying a stream of incoming data - cannot access property of undefined

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui

**EDIT**
This is the log for my request

```
$("#search_button").click(function(){
        var search = document.getElementById('search_text').value;
        $.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/search', {search_text: search, num_results: 2}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

            console.log(data);

        });
    });
```

[image]

**Background**
I'm fetching some data from my server and trying to display it on my page using the Onsen UI framework's Infinite List but I'm getting a `cannot access property 'text' of undefined`  error. I do see the data using `console.log(data)` so I hope there's not a problem with the request. I would really appreciate if someone could explain me what am I doing wrong here? Thanks 
**This Works**

I tried a basic example before fetching the data

```
ons.ready(function() {
  var data = [{"text":"Title 1"}, {"text":"Title 2"}]
  var infiniteList = document.getElementById('infinite-list');

  infiniteList.delegate = {
    createItemContent: function(i) {
      return ons.createElement(`<ons-list-item>
                                    <p style="color:DodgerBlue;">`+data[i].text+`</p>
                                    <img style="width:100%;" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/beautiful_scenery_04_hd_pictures_166258.jpg"/>
                                </ons-list-item>`);
    },
    countItems: function() {
      return data.length;
    }
  };

  infiniteList.refresh();
});
```

[image]

**This doesnt work**

```
 ons.ready(function(){

    $("#test_button").click(function(){

        $.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/search', {search_text: 'car', num_results: 2}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

            /*after success */

            var infiniteList = document.getElementById('infinite-list');

            infiniteList.delegate = {
            createItemContent: function(i) {
              return ons.createElement(`<ons-list-item>
                                            <p style="color:DodgerBlue;">`+data[i]+`</p>
                                            <img style="width:100%;" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/beautiful_scenery_04_hd_pictures_166258.jpg"/>
                                        </ons-list-item>`);
            },
            countItems: function() {
              return 2;
            }
          };

          infiniteList.refresh();

        });
    });
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

'Data' is limited to the function in which it is visible; it needs to be recognized where you are using it as well.

Use another variable which is declared outside both functions.

```
    var dataUse = [];//----------declare here so it is visible in every scope
     ons.ready(function(){

        $("#test_button").click(function(){

            $.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/search', {search_text: 'car', num_results: 2}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

                /*after success */
                dataUse = data;
                var infiniteList = document.getElementById('infinite-list');

                infiniteList.delegate = {
                createItemContent: function(i) {
                  return ons.createElement(`<ons-list-item>
                                                <p style="color:DodgerBlue;">`+dataUse[i]+`</p>
                                                <img style="width:100%;" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/beautiful_scenery_04_hd_pictures_166258.jpg"/>
                                            </ons-list-item>`);
                },
                countItems: function() {
                  return 2;
                }
              };

              infiniteList.refresh();

            });
        });
      });
```

Comment: That was some valuable information, Thank you. However I'm still seeing the same output as before

Comment: That seems like a step in the right direction. Now when I do `console.log(dataUse[i])` before returning `ons.createElement(...)` I do see the response but the log shows `{results:array(2)` and after that a few `undefined` as well

Comment: Pls post the response format in full. Using dataUse[i].text should give you the 'text' property if it exists.

Comment: Also, for the subsequent 'undefined's, pls also check the Dev Tools Network tab (Chrome) if the http results are as expected.